# Programmatically get class methods and properties?

Tags: php, oop

OK first, given a file, say `somefile.php` is there a way to search that file for a `Class`?

Then, once you have the class, is there a way to get all the public properties and method signatures?

I am trying to create a way to document PHP classes on the fly.

Comment: for future reference: this kind of capability is called Reflection. Knowing the right terms helps google help you :)

Comment: Why not simply use PHPDocumentor tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

include("somefile.php");

if (class_exists("MyClass")) {
 $myclass = new ReflectionClass("MyClass");

 // getMethods() returns an array of ReflectionMethod objects
 $methods = $myclass->getMethods();

 foreach ($methods as $method) {
    print $method->getName() . "():\n";

    // getParameters() returns an array of ReflectionParameter objects
    $parameters = $method->getParameters();
    foreach ($parameters as $parm) {
      print " " . $parm . "\n";
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php